# How to Return Top 10 Companies by earnings, by month

Tags: sql, database, report

I'm organizing data to display the top 10 customers by month, while also displaying the amount of sales appearing next to each value.

I've already looked up limits, top 10, and other possible solution, but given the way my code is structured, it doesn't seem possible.

I'd like for the top 10 results (Customer name followed by sales) to be shown per product code, on a monthly basis.

```
SELECT Distinct
        ASD.PRODUCT_CODE
       ,ASD.CUSTOMER
       ,ASD.SALES_AMT_NO_TAX
       ,MONTH(ASD.DATE) AS DATE_MONTH
       ,ASD.YEAR

    AND ASD.VSD  < '2019-09-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND ASD.VSD  >= '2017-04-01 00:00:00.000'   
    AND ASD.SALES_AMT_NO_TAX > 0
    AND ASD.PRODUCT_CODE in ('Product A','B','C','D',.....,'Z')

GROUP BY       
        MONTH(ASD.DATE)
       ,Year(ASD.DATE)
       ,ASD.PRODUCT_CODE
       ,ASD.CUSTOMER
       ,ASD.SALES_AMT_NO_TAX
       ,ASD.PURCHASE_AMOUNT
       ,ASD.DATE_QTR
       ,ASD.DATE_YEAR
```

Here's the format of how the results should come out once I mess with the pivot table in excel:

[image]

(Note this is my first post ever, so if there's anything I've missed, let me know! :)

Comment: Is order by not working?

Comment: GROUP BY, but no aggregate functions? Combined with SELECT DISTINCT?!?

Comment: @CeliusStingher I've tried 

ORDER BY ASD.SALES_AMT_NO_TAX DESC

Comment: @jarlh I am not a programmer by trade, so I am not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You want to break down your query into chucks by month and then union them together.

For example:

```
SELECT TOP (10)       
      ASD.CUSTOMER    
      ,ASD.SALES_AMT_NO_TAX
      ,MONTH(ASD.VSD) AS DATE_MONTH
      ,Year(ASD.VSD) as DATE_YEAR
  FROM ASD
  WHERE **Month(ASD.VSD) = 1**  
   AND ASD.VSD  < '2019-09-01 00:00:00.000'
   AND ASD.VSD  >= '2017-04-01 00:00:00.000'   
   AND ASD.SALES_AMT_NO_TAX > 0
   AND ASD.PRODUCT_CODE in ('Product A','B','C','D',.....,'Z')
  GROUP BY  ASD.CUSTOMER, ASD.SALES_AMT_NO_TAX, ASD.VSD
**UNION** 
SELECT TOP (10)       
      ASD.CUSTOMER    
      ,ASD.SALES_AMT_NO_TAX
      ,MONTH(ASD.VSD) AS DATE_MONTH
      ,Year(ASD.VSD) as DATE_YEAR
  FROM [AdventureWorks2016].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
  WHERE **Month(ASD.VSD) = 2**
   AND ASD.VSD  < '2019-09-01 00:00:00.000'
   AND ASD.VSD  >= '2017-04-01 00:00:00.000'   
   AND ASD.SALES_AMT_NO_TAX > 0
   AND ASD.PRODUCT_CODE in ('Product A','B','C','D',.....,'Z')
  GROUP BY  ASD.CUSTOMER, ASD.SALES_AMT_NO_TAX, ASD.VSD

    *REPEAT for all 3 through 11

**UNION** 
    SELECT TOP (10)       
          ASD.CUSTOMER    
          ,ASD.SALES_AMT_NO_TAX
          ,MONTH(ASD.VSD) AS DATE_MONTH
          ,Year(ASD.VSD) as DATE_YEAR
      FROM [AdventureWorks2016].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
      WHERE **Month(ASD.VSD) = 12**
       AND ASD.VSD  < '2019-09-01 00:00:00.000'
       AND ASD.VSD  >= '2017-04-01 00:00:00.000'   
       AND ASD.SALES_AMT_NO_TAX > 0
       AND ASD.PRODUCT_CODE in ('Product A','B','C','D',.....,'Z')
      GROUP BY  ASD.CUSTOMER, ASD.SALES_AMT_NO_TAX, ASD.VSD
      Order by DATE_YEAR, DATE_MONTH, ASD.CUSTOMER, ASD.SALES_AMT_NO_TAX, ASD.CUSTOMER
```

*Tip: It is also recommended to avoid using DISTICT and let your where conditions ensure your district records.*

*This example is for MS SQL Server.  The SQL/T-SQL code will differ based on type of DB. (MS SQL SERVER you would use the syntax:  Select top 10 vs Oracle you would use the syntax WHERE rownum <= 100)*